# How to assign a method to a method?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, typescript

Let's say I have an element id "`animObj`" which is animating on the screen. By virtue, I can have a method `getCurrentTime()` which is returning me the value of total time of animation run.

Now I am trying to assign a method to this method so that I can trace the change of time. My queries are as follow:

1. Is it possible if yes then What is wrong with my code as follows:

```js
var animObj = document.getElementById("animObj");
var parent = animObj.parentNode;

function timeUpdated(obj) {
  console.log(obj.getCurrentTime());
}
parent.getCurrentTime().onChange = function() {
  console.log(animObj.getCurrentTime());
}
```

```html
<svg width="576px" height="300px" ontimeupdate="timeUpdated(this)">
 
  <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="5" fill="black" id="animObj">
    <animateMotion path="M 0 150 H 576 Z" dur="5s" id='anim' repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </circle>
  
 
</svg>
```

2. If it's not possible then how to implement onTimeUpdate to this element.

Comment: What is the library you are using? what error messages do you see?

Comment: No libraries as well as no error but no output too. This is just for RnD I even tried mutationobsrerver too which also not working.

Comment: Just want to make sure you would like a call back whenever the return value of the getCurrentTime() is changed. Am I correct ?

Comment: Yes, you got the point! But I don't want to use setInterval or timeout as well.

Comment: There's no event when the current time changes. There really is no alternative to setInterval or timeout.

Comment: I have added the precise example. Please do let me know if something comes across.

Comment: @UllasHunka I don't think it is possible. Instead, I would recommend you add listener to animation start/pause. Because as long as the animation is playing, the time is always change and vice verse.

Comment: Please do suggest your answers in the answer!